# React TS - Return Object in use Context

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have created a filter Context as I wanted to keep it separate from my browse page. But I don't think I'm doing it correctly.
I first created types and interfaces like this:

```
type Brand = {
    brand:string;
    checked:boolean;
}
type Gender = {
    gender: "Male" | "Female" | "Kids";
    checked:boolean;
}
type Shoes = {
    brand:Brand[];
    gender:Gender[];
}
interface FilterProvider {
    FilterState:()=>{},
    updateGenderState: (value: string)=>void,
    updateBrandState: (value: string)=>void,
}
interface FilterProviderProps{
    children: ReactNode,
}
```

After in setting up my useContext

```
const FilterProvider = createContext({} as FilterProvider);

export const useFilterInfo = ()=>{
    return useContext(FilterProvider);
}
```

And at end then returning it like this:

```
export const FilterContext = ({children}: FilterProviderProps)=>{
    const [filterState,setFilterState] = useState<Shoes>({
        brand:[
            {
                brand:'New Balance',
                checked: false,
            },
            {
                brand:'Nike',
                checked: false,
            },
            {
                brand:'Addiddas',
                checked: false,
            },
            {
                brand:'Puma',
                checked: false,
            },
            {
                brand:'Converse',
                checked: false,
            },
            {
                brand:'Under Armour',
                checked: false,
            },
        ],
        gender:[{
            gender:'Male',
            checked:false,
        },
        {
            gender:'Female',
            checked:false,
        },
        {
            gender:'Kids',
            checked:false,
        }
    ],
    });

    const FilterState = ()=>{
        return filterState;
    }
    const updateGenderState = (value: string)=>{

    }
    const updateBrandState = (value: string)=>{

    }
    
    return  <FilterProvider.Provider value={{FilterState,updateBrandState,updateGenderState}}>
                {children}
            </FilterProvider.Provider>

}
```

The problem that I have is when I try and console log the `filterState` object it returns nothing. I think I have the wring return type if anyone can help.
thanks, I know the code is a bit long but I didn't want to leave anything out that people would ask for.
In the Filter file I called it like this:

```
import { useFilterInfo } from '../context/FilterContext'

export const Filter = (props:FilterProps)=>{
    const {FilterState,updateBrandState,updateGenderState} = useFilterInfo();
    console.log(JSON.stringify(FilterState));
...(rest of code)
```

Comment: I don't see any calls of `console.log()`, where did you call it?

Comment: i call in in a different file. i Import the Context and the functions but it returns undefined

Comment: It would be great if you can add the code of the file where you call `FilterContext`

Comment: ok ill edit the code and add it on, thanks

Comment: Do you call `FilterContext` somewhere above in the tree?

Comment: yes, i did the usual <FilterContext> </FilterContext> in the app.tsx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `FilterState` is a `function`, but you expect an `object` as I see from the code:

```
const {FilterState,updateBrandState,updateGenderState} = useFilterInfo();
console.log(JSON.stringify(FilterState));
```

You have to call `FilterState()`(because it's a function) for the object to be returned.

Comment: yep, it works, feel stupid ahah thanks